# MouseListener gets overshadoved by another JPanel component

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, mouselistener

[Program ScreenShot](http://s18.postimg.org/egemzjtu1/pix.png)

[image]

I'm making a animation. When I press on a button it triggers a animation which makes a `JPanel` float in from the right side. The `JPanel` gets `DeAnimated(JPanel exit animation)` when the mouse leaves the JPanel, but the problem is that I have a `JButton` on the animated `JPanel`. So the panel does not only disappear when i move the mouse out of the animated `JPanel` but also when I move the mouse on the button (which is a component of the panel), which means that when I want to click on the button it disappears, because the `MouseExit` is fired when the mouse leaves the `JPanel`.

Look at the picture above where I marked certain areas.

1. Is the JPanel which is getting animated and disappears when i move over the button.
2. Is the button which causes the JPanel to be DeAnimated.
3. Is the area which should trigger the DeAnimation of the 1st JPanel.

I have been trying to fix this for a long time now, but I can't get it working. I would really appreciate it if you guys could help me. Thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The explanation is hard too read. Use panel1, panel2, and panel3 as depicted in your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"but the problem is that I have a JButton on the animated JPanel. "*

**Don't put the button on the same panel then**. Learn to use layout managers. With your image, I would use nested `JPanel`s with `BorderLayout`s

The right side

```
JButton button = new JButton();
JPanel animatedPanel = new JPanel();
```

Add them to another JPanel

```
JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
rightPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
rightPanel.add(animatedPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

 /**      result       **/

       +-----+
       |     |
       |     |
       +-----+
       |     |
       |     |
       |     |
       |     |
       |     |
       +-----+
```

Then create another JPanel to hold the BigPanel and the RightPanel

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel leftBigPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.add(leftBigPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(rightPanel);

          /**       result       **/

         *--------------------+-----+
         |                    |     |
         |                    |     |
         |                    +-----+
         |                    |     |
         |                    |     |
         |                    |     |
         |                    |     |
         |                    |     |
         +--------------------+-----+
```

The button no longer overlaps the right animated panel

- **Note** : @override the `getPreferredSize()` in the JPanels for your desired dimension.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that i need to have the button on the Panel, because the button gets animated into the frame with the JPanel. I tried what you wrote, but because i have another panel over the animated panel when i move the mouse from one panel to another the MouseExit method gets fired, even though i just moved to another panel/button.